# Filtration over tensor product

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, filtrations

Let
$$ M \supset M_1 \supset \ldots \supset M_n \supset \ldots \text{ and } N \supset N_1 \supset \ldots \supset N_n \supset \ldots$$
be exhaustive decreasing filtrations of modules over a commutative integral ring $R$. I would like to know if there is any way to define a filtration over $M \otimes_R N$ such that the graduation $Gr_k(M \otimes_r N)$ verifies
$$Gr_k(M \otimes_r N)=\oplus_{i+j=k} M_i/M_{i+1}\otimes_RN_j/N_{j+1}.$$
I know it is possible to do so in the case of finite dimensional vector spaces by defining
$$(M \otimes_R N)_k=\sum_{i+j=k}M_i \otimes N_j.$$
So if anyone has an idea or a reference where something like could be written, I would appreciate. Thanks for reading me.

Comment: If this were possible, it would in particular imply that $[M \otimes_R N] = \sum_{i,j} [\operatorname{Gr}_i M \otimes \operatorname{Gr}_j N]$ in the Grothendieck group of $R$. But this is not always true; for example let $R$ be a Dedekind domain admitting a prime ideal $\mathfrak p \subseteq R$ of order $>1$ in the class group, and let $M_0 \supsetneq M_1 \supsetneq M_2$ be $R \supseteq I \supseteq 0$ and $N_0 \supsetneq N_1$ be $R/\mathfrak p \supseteq 0$.

Comment: Then $M \otimes N \cong R/\mathfrak p$ and $M_0/M_1 \otimes N \cong R/\mathfrak p \cong M_1/M_2 \otimes N$. Since $K_0(R) \cong \operatorname{Cl}(R) \oplus \mathbf Z$ (taking $R/\mathfrak p$ to $(\mathfrak p,0)$ and $R$ to $(0,1)$), we see that the two do not coincide. (There might be a positive statement in general if you use the *derived* tensor product $M \otimes_R^{\mathbf L} N$.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't thought about such examples in the first place. Is there any chance it would be true if we add the condition that M and N are flat ?

Comment: You can make a similar example where $N_0 \supsetneq N_1 \supsetneq N_2$ is also $R \supset I \supset 0$. I think a better condition would be that $M_i/M_{i+1}$ and $N_i/N_{i+1}$ are flat, and then the construction you suggest should probably work.

Comment: Okay ! I can add this conditions to my theorem so thank you very much !

Comment: Hello again, I'm sorry to ask you again but I didn't succeeded to prove it by myself, do you have any references of books or articles that prove such a thing ? Thank you very much

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of the case of finite length filtrations, where you construct it by induction on the length of one of them. Does that work, or is there an issue with this? I'm not sure about the infinite case. I'm not aware of any references, but that doesn't mean they don't exist (this type of auxiliary result can sometimes be hard to find ― it could be in a paper about something completely different).

Comment: I must admit I didn't try such a proof cause I don't have any références on it. Basically I just read an article of Deligne (Hodge Mixte theory 2) and Bourbaki. So if you have anything close even in the finite filtration case I would be happy to read it and learn

Comment: I know this is an old question, but this may help: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.1359.pdf

Comment: @FunctionOfX I did gave some extra info thanks !